# Topology retraction and weak expectation property

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a $C^*$-Algebra $A\subseteq\mathbb{B}(H)$ (for some Hilbert Space $H$), a linear mapping $V:\mathbb{B}(H)\rightarrow A^{\ast\ast}$ is called a **generalized weak expectation** if $\|V\|\leq 1$ and $V(a)=a$ for each $a\in A$. Such $A$ is said to have **Lance's weak expectation property** (or **WEP**). More details of **WEP** and properties of $V$ can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06224).

Given a topological space $X$ and a subspace $A$, a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow A$ is a **retraction** if $f(a)=a$ for each $a\in A$. Since $A^{\ast\ast}$ is the weak-$\ast$ closure of $A$ and the weak-$\ast$ closure of $A$, say $\overline{A}^{w\ast}$, is contained in $\mathbb{B}(H)$, then there will be a mapping say $\Psi$ from $\mathbb{B}(H)$ to the $\overline{A}^{w\ast}$ such that for each $a\in\overline{A}^{w\ast}, \Psi(a)=a$.

My question are the following:

1. in a $C^*$-Algebra, is there a property that is similar to the existence of a deformation retract, or strong deformation retract?
2. Is there any relation between the concept of retraction and the concept of **WEP** (since their definitions are so similar)? Languages in topology and $C^*$-Algebra are different in general but I wish to see some concepts that look similar, and any examples or explanations will be highly appreciated.